# why the content area of inline-block is stretch

Tags: css

why the content area of inline-block is stretch

```css
div {
  background: green;
  line-height: 40px;
}
span {
  background: white;
}
#inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div><span id="inline-block">AAA</span><span>AAA</span></div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: @DanWhite is about inline-block, not position.

Comment: No, `#inline-block` is about inline-block, `<div>` has a static position and no display properties at all. Also, it isn't stretched in any way. `<div>` is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/xcyvhphc/

html:

```
<div>
  <span>AAA</span>
  <span>AAA</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
  background: green;
  line-height: 40px; # or height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

read more about inline-block and other css display properties [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior. You set `line-height` equal to 40px, so that becomes the height of your content, including `spans`. However the second `span` is `inline` (default), so `line-height` doesn't work on it and its height remains unchanged.

If you want your `div` to be 40px tall, use `height: 40px;` instead of `line-height: 40px;`